# How to Add Meta Title and Description in Yoast with WordPress Rest API?

Tags: wordpress, rest, yoast

I'm trying to add a title and description in Yoast with WordPress rest API, but I didn't found any way of doing so. If you know, please help me :)

Answer (score 0):

to be able to add meta from rest api you have to set
'show_in_rest' => true
when registering the meta, which is already registered by yoast itself and they not set the 'show_in_rest' option to true.

so you have to create a plugin to change that option to true.
6 years ago you can use this plugin https://github.com/ChazUK/wp-api-yoast-meta
but i don't know for now, is it still working or not